# Configurar compresion gzip en vue

Tags: vue.js, gzip

Quiero comprimir mis archivos para que la app cargue mas rapido.

Pretendo usar este compresor:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-compression

La documentación dice que configure de la siguiente manera

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    compression:{
      brotli: {
        filename: '[file].br[query]',
        algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
        include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
        compressionOptions: {
          params: {
            [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_QUALITY]: 11,
          },
        },
        minRatio: 0.8,
      },
      gzip: {
        filename: '[file].gz[query]',
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
        minRatio: 0.8,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pero recibo el error `zlib is not defined`.

Tambien intento agregar esta funcion

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config
        .plugins('brotli-compression')
        .plugins('gzip-compression')
  }
```

Dejando el código asi:

```
module.exports = {
      chainWebpack: config => {
         config
            .plugins('brotli-compression')
            .plugins('gzip-compression')
      },
      pluginOptions: {
        compression:{
          brotli: {
            filename: '[file].br[query]',
            algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
            include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
            compressionOptions: {
              params: {
                [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_QUALITY]: 11,
              },
            },
            minRatio: 0.8,
          },
          gzip: {
            filename: '[file].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
            minRatio: 0.8,
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Y me dice que config.plugin no es una funcion.

Quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de configurar el pluguin para obtener una build comprimida. Muchas gracias.